# Get list of all the routes in vue project and generate site map - Vue Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Suppose I created an route as:
router.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from " vue-router";
import BookRoutes from "./routes/book";

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    routes:[
        {
            path: "/book",
            name: "book",
            component:{
               render(c) {
                  return c("router-view")
                }
            },
            childern: BookRoutes

        }
    ]
})
```

Routes-> book -> index.js

```
const BookProfile = () => 
import (/* webpackChunkNames: "BookProfile" */ "@/components/profile/book/BookProfile")

import BookRoutes from "./Book";

export default [{path: 
                "book/:bookId",
                "name": "profile.book",
                 redirect: {name: "profile.book.fee"},
                 component: BookProfile,
                 children: BookRoutes
                 
               }]
```

Book.Js:

```
const BookFee = () => import (/* webpackChunkName: "BookProfilr" */)

export default:[{
    path: "book-fee",
    name: "profile.book.fee",
    component: BookFee
}]
```

In same way almost list of routes are created, how to get list of all routes, if possible with the id filled, if not list of all the routes that are created in vue project.

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<template>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
        <router-link :to="item.name">{{item.name}}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$router.options.routes.forEach(route => {
            this.items.push({
                name: route.name,
                path: route.path
            })
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this give url for all the nested or normal routes as well? Can you please suggest me best way to generate sitemap for all url as there are very limited articles on this.

Comment: The best way to solve your problem is to use the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-sitemap

Comment:  support dynamic routes with single or multiple parameters
 support nested routes

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getRoutes` method of the router instance in any child component like :

```
mounted(){
 let routes = this.$router.getRoutes()

}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. I am very new to vue js and completely unable to understand. Could you please provide with an example or with any article that I can refer to. I don't understand where can I use getRoutes method and how to use it.

Comment: P.S.: I want to get list of all the routes at once in list, if it's possible.

Comment: Try that this.$router.options.routes